# MoS2 (Transition Metal Dichalcogenide) layer using Mathematica

Tags: rotation

I'm trying to generate Transition metal dichalcogenide monolayer (MoS2). Can you please assist me with this problem

Thanks and regards

Mo 0.00   0.00 0.1682
S  0.666 0.666 0.2124
S   0.666 0.666 0.12412

Following code I use to generate  graphene monolayer. Now I need a monolayer MoS2 system. In graphene all the atoms were in one plane (1 layer). But in MoS2 we have to use z coordinates as well.

(* graphene*)

```
    `nshell = 30;
     a1 =  {Cos[-30 Degree], Sin[-30 Degree]};
     a2 =  {Cos[30 Degree], Sin[30 Degree]};
     \[Delta] = (a1 + a2)/3;
     L1a = 1. Flatten[
     Table[
      Table[i a1 + j a2 + \[Delta], {j, -nshell, nshell}], {i, - 
      nshell,
      nshell}], 1];

      L1b = 1. Table[i + \[Delta], {i, L1a}];
       ListPlot[{Join[L1a, L1b]}]`
```

[image: graphene monolayer]

(*MoS2*)
`c1 = 3.16;
c2 = (0.242^2) - ((3.16)^2)/3;
c3 = 3.5;

```
     a1 = {c1, 0, 0};
     a2 = {-c1/2, Sqrt[3]/2 c1, 0};
     a3 = {0, 0, 2 c2 + c3};

     \[Delta] = {{c1, 0, 0}, {-c1/2, Sqrt[3]/2 c1, 0}, {0, 0, (2 
      c2 + c3)}};
     ListPlot3D[\[Delta]]`
```

[image]
[image]

Thank you very much for the answer.
[image]

The lattice may rotate as in this picture starting from (0,0,0) coordinates ( All the coordinates should positive).

Comment: What is it you want to do exactly? Generate graphics of the crystal structure?

Comment: Yes I want to generate the coordinates of the monolayer.

Comment: On this forum, you have to demonstrate that you tried some steps toward the solution. Please, show your code.

Comment: So do you want to generate _graphics_ or just the _coordinates_ then? Your answer is unclear.

Comment: I have attached the code I am using for monolayer graphene. I want to make a MoS2 monolayer.

Comment: I need coordinates

Answer (score 1):

### Edit 01:

The original question asked about a commensurate MoS$_2$ moire. It has since been updated to ask about only the coordinates of an MoS$_2$ monolayer. Considering the answer to the original question might be useful to other people, I'll leave this up. The answer to the updated question only can be found in the second code block.

### Original answer

The commensurability of the moire cell is a property of the lattice vectors, not the motif. As such - you can use the following to compute the commensurate angles and commensurate moire cell for two twisted hexagonal lattices (with the same lattice constant):

```mathematica
hexagonalLattice[hexagonalLatticeConstant_] := 
 hexagonalLatticeConstant {{Sqrt[3]/2, 1/2}, {-(Sqrt[3]/2), 1/2}}
commensurateRotationAngle[{m_, n_}] := 
 With[{cos = (n^2 + 4 n m + m^2)/(2 (n^2 + n m + m^2))}, ArcCos[cos]]
commensurateCell[latticeVectors_, {m_,n_}] := {{n,-m}.latticeVectors, {m,n+m}.latticeVectors}
```

After that, it's a matter of decorating the moire cell with the appropriate honeycomb motif for each layer. Here is an example of a (6,7) commensurate moire cell for twisted bilayer MoS$_2$:

```mathematica
moS2Lattice = ArrayPad[hexagonalLattice[3.19], {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, 0.];
moS2Lattice[[3, 3]] = 14.879;

distance["Mo-S"] = 1/10;
moS2BilayerMotif = {
   {1/3, 2/3, 1/4}, {2/3, 1/3, 1/4 + distance["Mo-S"]}, {2/3, 1/3, 
    1/4 - distance["Mo-S"]},
   {2/3, 1/3, 3/4}, {1/3, 2/3, 3/4 + distance["Mo-S"]}, {1/3, 2/3, 
    3/4 - distance["Mo-S"]}};
```

Note I define the full bilayer motif here, the first three coordinates refer to the bottom layer, while the last three to the top layer.

We can visualize this to make sure it looks correct for the untwisted case:

```mathematica
cols = Association[Map[ElementData[#, "AtomicSymbol"] -> ElementData[#, "IconColor"] &, {"Molybdenum", "Sulfur"}]];
moS2Colors = {Darker[cols["Mo"]], Darker[cols["S"]], Darker[cols["S"]], cols["Mo"], cols["S"], cols["S"]};
Graphics3D[
 Thread[{moS2Colors, 
   Sphere /@ (Outer[Plus, moS2BilayerMotif, 
       Tuples[{Range[-3, 3], Range[-3, 3], {0}}], 1] . moS2Lattice)}],
  ViewPoint -> {0, \[Infinity], 0}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Now, we can make two large copies of an untwisted bottom layer and a twisted top layer, and then punch out the atoms inside our moire cell:

```mathematica
moireCellRM = 
  RegionMember[
   Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}} . 
     commensurateCell[moS2Lattice[[;; 2, ;; 2]], {6, 7}]]];

moS2Bottom = 
  Table[Select[atom, 
    moireCellRM[#[[;; 2]]] &], {atom, (Outer[Plus, 
       Take[moS2BilayerMotif, 3], 
       Tuples[{Range[-20, 20], Range[-20, 20], {0}}], 1] . 
      moS2Lattice)}];

moS2Top = 
  Table[Select[atom, 
    moireCellRM[#[[;; 2]]] &], {atom, (Outer[Plus, 
       Drop[moS2BilayerMotif, 3], 
       Tuples[{Range[-20, 20], Range[-20, 20], {0}}], 1] . 
      RotationTransform[commensurateRotationAngle[{6, 7}], {0, 0, 1}][
       moS2Lattice])}];
```

Let's visualize these to make sure it looks correct:

```mathematica
singleCell = {
   Thread[{Take[moS2Colors, 3], Sphere /@ moS2Bottom}],
   Thread[{Drop[moS2Colors, 3], Sphere /@ moS2Top}]};

twistedMoire = 
 Graphics3D[singleCell, ViewPoint -> {0, 0, \[Infinity]}, 
  Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 350]
```

[image]

and finally tile the plane to make it even clearer:

```mathematica
twistedMoireLarge = Graphics3D[
   Table[
    GeometricTransformation[singleCell, 
     TranslationTransform[{i, j, 1} . 
       ArrayPad[
        commensurateCell[
         moS2Lattice[[;; 2, ;; 2]], {6, 7}], {{0, 1}, {0, 
          1}}]]], {i, -1, 1}, {j, -1, 1}], 
   ViewPoint -> {0, 0, \[Infinity]}, Boxed -> False, 
   ImageSize -> 750] // Rasterize
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate the informative explanation at each step. This is what exactly what I needed. I have to use this in Lammps molecular dynamics simulation.  Can you please print the coordinates and lattice vectors. All the coordinates should be positive. It is better if the structure is starting at (0,0,0) in positive direction.  Lattice vectors example:                                                                                         138.493620415 0.0 0.0
69.246810207 119.938993541 0.0
0.0 0.0 35.0